# how to use rails model attributes inside sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use a string value (hex) that's submitted through a form as the background-color for a div class.

The form is:
`<%= f.text_field :backgroundcolor %>`

The html is:
`<div class="bottle"></bottle>`

And the css is:

```
.bottle {
background-color: <%= color.backgroundcolor %>
}
```

But I just get an invalid css error. How do I use these attributes in the sass? I could use them as inline css, but would prefer not to.

Comment: How are you planning to call `<%= color` in the CSS?

Comment: That's just it. I have `<% @colors.each do |color| %>` in my view. That works because it's an erb file. I just don't know how to make that work in a sass. Adding ".erb" to the end (as mentioned elsewhere) is leading me nowhere, so I assume that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you'd get the result you want is if you [persisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) the data (stored in the DB).

---

**CSS**

If the `color` var was available from the db, or some other source, you'd be able to call it into the CSS:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
.bottle
   background-color: <%= Option.find_by(title: "color").value %>
```

This will give you access to the value stored in our fictitious model... however, it would **not** update on the fly (IE form submit).

Whenever you push your code to "production", Rails will expect to ["precompile"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) the assets.

Precompilation is where all the assets are concatenated into single files (typically `application.css`). This process makes your assets **static**. Indeed, `SASS` / `SCSS` are just [preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) for this process (they run before the minifier).

Whilst you *can* make your assets dynamic in production (as they are in dev), it drastically slows down your web app (it has to compile the assets for EACH call).

--

To resolve your issue, you'd best put your custom styling *either* into the `<head>` of the page, or inline on one of the elements:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  <style>
    .bottle { background-color: "<%= Color.find_by(name: 'bottle').value %>" }
  </style>
</head>
```

...or...

```
<%= content_tag :div, style: "background-color: #{color.background-color}" %>
```

No, I don't like it either, but if you want dynamic values, that's what would have to be done. There are some alternatives, but you'll have to hack them together from the backend.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've got a color model with validated attributes and a schema table. So my data IS persisted. I never thought about the sass files being static, but that's a really good point. Thanks for your help!